# Definition of configuration tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just tagged a question with [configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration), referring to [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration). However, the tag is probably otherwise used for any general configuration problem.

What definition of the the tag do we want?

Comment: [tag:libraries] has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the tag for the module is much better, IMO. It would be too broad, if it is used for any configuration question.

The tag is actually used from the following questions, which have very few in common:

- [How to choose between Bean, Boxes and Fieldable Panels Panes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39525/how-to-choose-between-bean-boxes-and-fieldable-panels-panes)
- [Parsing a multi-valued theme-setting into to two defaults results in theme-settings not saving](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38787/parsing-a-multi-valued-theme-setting-into-to-two-defaults-results-in-theme-setti)
- [Cannot access configuration pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37317/cannot-access-configuration-pages)
- [Configure Modules from a Script](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35528/configure-modules-from-a-script)

Considering there is also [settings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings), I would keep [configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) for the module. Instead of [configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration), we could use [configuration.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration.module), if the risk of misusing the tag is high.

What I would do is:

- Use [configuration.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration.module) for the question about the module
- Merge [configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) with [settings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings) (without to make them synonyms)
- (Eventually) Rename [configuration.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration.module) as [configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)

Comment: I've retagged my question with configuration.module. I suggest we consider the above answer official policy for now :)